# Clear and simple rules for deciding between checked and unchecked exceptions

Tags: java, exception

Since there is a lot of ambiguity about this, can we come up with some clear, simple and easy to use rules?

Here is a first try, these three rules should be sufficient for all cases.

---

*First rule is based on the common principle that implementation details of the method should not be exposed to the caller:*

**Rule 1:**
Checked exception should not expose implementation details to the caller:
You can test it this way: If you completely change the implementation but still expect the method to fulfill its contract (like in refactoring) would it still make sense to throw the exception?
If yes then it should be a Checked exception because it is not implementation detail but part of use case the method fullfills.
If no then the exception should be unchecked because it is an implementation detail which should not be exposed to the caller.

*If based on Rule 1 the exception should be checked then apply the Rule 2:*

**Rule 2**: Since checked exception is part of the method contract, violation of the method's contract can't be a checked exception.
For example this method executes sql query from its param:

`executeSqlQuery(String sqlQuery)`

If caller provides string that is not an sql query then he violated input conditions of the method and the resulting exception must be unchecked.

*If based on Rule 2 the exception still seems like checked, apply rule three which checks whether the method is following another best practice: single responsibility principle*

**Rule 3**: Method should do just one thing.
For example method

`List.get(int index)`

is correctly doing just one thing: returning desired element from the list. And not trying to also fulfill another common use cases: check whether the element is present.
On the other hand method

`findById(Long id) throws RecordNotFoundException`

is incorrectly trying to mix these two functions and by that forces all callers to always consider the use case when record is not found even though they know that the record exists.

---

Is some rule missing or can we simplify and clarify the rules further?

---

**BACKGROUND:**
There are many different views on this topic. There is quite a lot of proponents of "radical" solutions like never to use a checked exception (some java books or designers of C#) or that almost everything should be a checked exception (IOException in java.io package or SQLException in JDBC).
And at least same number of views suggest to use both types but are offering subjective and ambiguous rules for deciding between them which without a lengthy explanation that is often missing instead of helping just bring more confusion (eg: If it is reasonable for the caller to recover from the exception than it should be checked.  Is trying the call again a reasonable recovery? For some clients it may be. Words reasonable and recover are too ambiguous.)

Answer (score 3):

Um, that question is answered in the official [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html), in fact:

> Here's the bottom line guideline: If a client can reasonably be expected to recover from an exception, make it a checked exception. If a client cannot do anything to recover from the exception, make it an unchecked exception.

That looks like a pretty clear, simple rule to me.

**EDIT**: your *background* edit explains your confusion and frustration quite well. If you want to, I can come up with a even simpler rule:

> Always be usable. Try to be practical where possible. Strive to be consistent.

The point is that exception handling is something that the user of the method that might throw must do. Sadly, Java forces the person who writes that method to make the choice for the user of that method. Thus, I'm leaning slightly towards the "never do checked" side, because your methods will always be *usable*. For some cases, for example network I/O, it might be really *practical* to force the user to build in some error handling, but that's not really often the case. If you're asking yourself *hm, my last 400 methods all threw `RuntimeError`s, should this now throw a checked exception?*, attaining *consistence* might make using your library more *practical*.

Sadly, this rule is easier, but not clearer, because at least *practical* and *consistent* are very subjective notions. So here you are, stuck with something that is really a question of *style*.

Comment: Thanks, I know about this rule, but is is not useful in practice. I added some background to the question about why I am asking.

Comment: This rule is "as useful as it's going to get" in practice.  You are writing code for someone else to use (if you care about these things), so put yourself in their shoes.  Do you want them to write a try - catch block?  If that means it is a pain to use your stuff because they can't recover, then you picked the wrong choice.  If it fails in a recoverable way, an unchecked exception will make it very difficult to just "know" where to put the try - catch block without some pretty ugly experimentation.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response, I am upvoting it. But I still think that we can decide based on the fact whether exception is part of the contract or not. And if it is part of the contract  it is actually good for the user of the method to be forced to account for that exception because if he does not then he has a bug in his code.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental problem with the way Java handles checked exceptions is that while it would be useful to distinguish exceptions that get thrown for expected reasons (e.g. `getRecordById` throwing a `RecordNotFoundException` when given an ID that doesn't exist) from those which get thrown for unexpected reasons (e.g. a method which calls `getRecordId` for an ID which is supposed to exist, but doesn't), the *type* of an exception has little to do with whether it's coming from a method for reasons that method knows about, or because it was unexpectedly thrown in a nested method call.

If Java allowed exception instances to be marked as "expected" or "unexpected", with distinct statements for catching expected and unexpected ones as well as a means of indicating that any methods within a block aren't expected to throw certain exceptions (and if any such exceptions that are thrown are marked as "expected", they should be flagged "unexpected" before propagating out) then having certain methods declared as throwing "expected" exceptions would be useful.  Given the present architecture, however, it's better to simply declare most exceptions as being unchecked.

Comment: Thanks, this is kind of what I had in mind, that checked exceptions are expected.

Comment: @mmm: That was the intention, I think.  The problem is that in many cases where code throws an exception, some callers will be expecting it and others won't.  The "default", from a language standpoint, should be that exceptions should be considered "unexpected", but Java requires programmers to say that any checked expectations are "expected", whether they really are or not, and makes it awkward for code to handle exceptions as "unexpected".